# How to bind an ObservableMap to a ListViewer or TableViewer?

Tags: jface, eclipse-databinding

There are plenty of examples on how to bind a Set or a List to a Viewer using the `ObservableSetContentProvider` or `ObservableListContentProvider`. However, I could not find anything about a `ObservableMapContentProvider` or a way to bind a viewer to a `HashMap` that implements the `IObservableMap` interface.

Usage examples:

- Binding to show the map keys in a `ListViewer
- Binding to show the map entries in a table viewer where the key is one column and the Value properties are other columns.

I know that in EMF it is possible to do this with `EMap`, but how would it be done for an `ObservableMap`.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?